# Remove levels and set index 0 as columns names

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to remove first line with names `level_0` and all and convert index `0` as columns.

### My df

```
        level_0      level_1         level_2           SVM Data LIF Name        LIF IP             VLAN                    Gateway            Subnet      DNS Name  Storage Port                       Hostname        FQDN.1         IP Address   Subnet Mask Gateway.1
0  Storage Site          SVM   Data LIF Name        LIF IP          VLAN       Gateway           Subnet                       FQDN          DNS Name  Storage Port      Hostname                           FQDN    IP Address        Subnet Mask       Gateway      VLAN
1        Munich  stlab308vs1  stlab308vs1-l1  192.168.1118           564  192.168.1117  255.255.255.240  Hostname&tt-example.com  tt-example.com  Cluster Mgmt      stlab308      stlab308.tt-example.com  192.168.13.34  \n255.255.255.192  192.168.13.62         2
2        Munich  stlab308vs1  stlab308vs1-l2  192.168.1119           564  192.168.1117  255.255.255.240  Hostname&tt-example.com  tt-example.com    Node1-Mgmt    stlab308n1    stlab308n1.tt-example.com  192.168.13.35  \n255.255.255.192  192.168.13.62         2
3        Munich  Replication    stlab308_ic1  192.168.1120           564  192.168.1117  255.255.255.240  Hostname&tt-example.com  tt-example.com      Node1-SP  stlab308n1sp  stlab308n1sp.tt-example.com  192.168.13.36  \n255.255.255.192  192.168.13.62         2
4        Munich  Replication    stlab308_ic2  192.168.1121           564  192.168.1117  255.255.255.240  Hostname&tt-example.com  tt-example.com    Node2-Mgmt    stlab308n2    stlab308n2.tt-example.com  192.168.13.37  \n255.255.255.192  192.168.13.62         2
5        Munich                                                                                                                                           Node2-SP  stlab308n2sp  stlab308n2sp.tt-example.com  192.168.13.38  \n255.255.255.192  192.168.13.62         2
```

### code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_excel

my_sheet = "test"
file_name = 'Lab_Storage_Installation_Tracker.xlsx'

df = read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = my_sheet, header=None, names=['SVM', 'Data LIF Name', 'LIF IP', 'VLAN', 'Gateway', 'Subnet', 'DNS Name', 'Storage Port', 'Hostname', 'FQDN.1', 'IP Address', 'Subnet Mask', 'Gateway.1'])
#df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
df.columns = [col[1] for col in df.columns]
print(df)
```

~
~

I tried like below but not working..

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
```

OR

```
df.columns = [col[1] for col in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest first create `MultiIndex in columns` by `header=[0,1]` by convert first 2 headers rows:

```
df = read_excel(file_name, sheet_name = my_sheet, header=[0,1])
```

And then if necessary remove `level_` labels is possible create tuples with empty strings instead `level_` values in first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
L = [('', b) if a.startswith('level_') else (a,b) for a, b in df.columns]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L)
```

Then if need selecting need tuple with both levels:

```
#if first levels is empty string
print (df[('','SVM')])
#if specified both levels
print (df[('SVM','LIF IP')])
```